# Order confirm email translation issue Magento 2

Tags: email, magento2, translate, confirm

Our Magento 2.1.5 site is ready to translate all email templates.
But, when a customer creates order, he got non-translated order confirm email immediately. To check this issue, when we click "send email" tab on order view page on admin, we get the correctly translated email.

[Send order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pvcl.png)

What was wrong?

We found this email template which was just order_new.html on theme folder.

```
app\design\frontend\[vendor]\[theme]\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html
```

Also, this template was assigned on vendor.

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\etc\email_templates.xml

<template id="sales_email_order_template" label="New Order" file="order_new.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you still have this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue successfully.

This is solution.

Original:

@subject Your {{var store.getFrontendName()}} order confirmation @

My Solution:

@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName() }}@